Azure Cosmos Synapse Link - null fields within object default to 0 in SQL
I have a Cosmos database in Well-Defined schema mode. I have a Synapse Serverless SQL instance. I have documents in Cosmos with objects that contain fields with null values. When I create a View for the Container in SQL the null object values are appearing as 0, why would it do this?
Example:
Here's a doc in Cosmos (object highlighted in yellow with null fields):




Could you please provide the sample code with sample data? And can I know what did you do in serverless SQL instance?

Thanks for looking @Bhavani, please see added example above.

Please don't upload images of code, [edit] your question to format code using [code block].

When I read the document from cosmos db in serverless SQL pool I faced the same issue as shown below:

The null values in AddressDetails are being replaced with 0. This suggests that the SQL Server engine (or the underlying JSON parser used by OPENROWSET) is interpreting line1, line2, and postcode as numeric fields (probably integers), as shown below:

And 0 is their default value. That may be the reason to get AddressDetails in above format. You can use below query to transform the AddressDetails field as required:
SELECT 
    JSON_QUERY(
        CONCAT(
            '{"line1":', 
            CASE WHEN JSON_VALUE(AddressDetails, '$.line1') <> '0' THEN JSON_VALUE(AddressDetails, '$.line1') ELSE 'null' END, 
            ',"line2":', 
            CASE WHEN JSON_VALUE(AddressDetails, '$.line2') <> '0' THEN JSON_VALUE(AddressDetails, '$.line2') ELSE 'null' END, 
            ',"postcode":', 
            CASE WHEN JSON_VALUE(AddressDetails, '$.postcode') <> '0' THEN JSON_VALUE(AddressDetails, '$.postcode') ELSE 'null' END, 
           
            '}'
        )
    ) AS AddressDetails_Transformed
FROM OPENROWSET(
    PROVIDER = 'CosmosDB',
    CONNECTION = 'Account=csmsdbs;Database=db',
    OBJECT = 'c1',
    SERVER_CREDENTIAL = 'MyCosmosDbAccountCredential'
) AS [c1];


JSON_VALUE: Extracts individual JSON fields from the AddressDetails column using the JSON path ($.fieldName).
CASE Logic: Replaces 0 with null.
CONCAT: Constructs the JSON object as a string.
JSON_QUERY: Ensures the result is treated as valid JSON.

You can get the output as shown below:


The only problem with the above is if 0 is a valid field value. I've played a bit more and discovered if null is used for an object field value and there is no other document where the field is defined with an actual value, then the field will be returned as 0 in SQL Synapse. Solution: don't define null in documents where there are no documents  where the field has been given an actual value.
